# Webkit browser displaying blank

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, webkit, puppeteer, playwright

I'm using playwright to display an SAPUI5 applicaiton on a Webkit browser.
It loads on Chromium and Firefox, it's just blank.
My code is shown below:

```
const playwright = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  for (const browserType of ['chromium', 'firefox', 'webkit']) {
    const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/cart/webapp/index.html?sap-ui-theme=sap_fiori_3#/categories");
    await page.screenshot({ path: `example-${browserType}.png` });
    await browser.close();
  }
})();
```

Is there a way to display the website on webkit browser?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in poor Internet connection or some issues with site loading.
I've solved the same issue by creating one additional script.
Create next script(separate js file):

```
const browser = {
        chrome: 'chromium',
        firefox: 'firefox',
        safari: 'webkit'
    };
    
    const getLoadDocument = (browser) => {
        switch (browser) {
            case browser.chromium:
                return 'domcontentloaded';
            case browser.firefox:
                return 'load';
            default:
                return 'domcontentloaded';
        }
    };
    
    module.exports = ({
        browser,
        getLoadDocument
    });
```

and try to add it in your code like this:

```
const playwright = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  for (const browserType of ['chromium', 'firefox', 'webkit']) {
    const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/cart/webapp/index.html?sap-ui-theme=sap_fiori_3#/categories");
    await page.waitForLoadState(helpers.getLoadDocument(browserType))
    await page.screenshot({ path: `example-${browserType}.png` });
    await browser.close();
  }
})();
```

I guess it will help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `{ waitUntil: "networkidle" }` to your `page.goto` call, that would mean, that it will wait until there is a 500ms network idle on your web page. Normally, that would mean, that the web page is finished with loading, but this website seems quite slow.

As a workaround you then have a few options, probably for your case is the best if you wait for a specific element (.click() will also wait for an element), are you are trying to write tests?

Alternatively you can use `waitForTimeout` to wait for an amount of time.

Like that in the end:

```
// @ts-check
const playwright = require("playwright");

(async () => {
  // Try to add 'firefox' to the list ↓
  for (const browserType of ['chromium', 'webkit', 'firefox']) {
    /** @type {import('playwright').Browser} */
    const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/cart/webapp/index.html?sap-ui-theme=sap_fiori_3#/categories", {
      waitUntil: "networkidle"
    });
    await page.waitForSelector("text=Accessories")
    await page.screenshot({ path: `example-${browserType}.png` });
    await browser.close();
  }
})();
```

See here interactively: https://try.playwright.tech/?s=36u3d

Comment: Yeah i'm attempting to run tests to generate screenshots of different pages in the application. I've tried using networkidle and waitfortimeout, but the screenshot it still returning blank. I'm writing the tests in VS code on my local machine.

Comment: If you don't know how the web page will look like, then waitForTimeout seems to be unfortunately the best solution. Probably its an issue on SAP UI5 side, that the site is so slow.

Comment: The site does work with the playwright playground. I also just found out that the website can load if i open devtools and subsequently reload the browser. I'm not sure what to make of it though.